# Matplotlib fade line behind transparent text box

Tags: text, matplotlib, transparency, box

I would like to place a text box directly over a line plot that would cause the line at that point to 'fade', for legibility. My first thought is to change alpha of the text box. However that requires me to set a background colour, which I do not want (the plot background is currently transparent, which I would like to keep). There may be other elements of various shapes/colours that would be similarly stacked under the text. Ideally, what I want is a semi-opaque text box that has no colour of its own, but which would cause elements underneath the text box to be half-hidden. Alpha seems to be not the way to go, but is there another attribute that I can modify?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.mpl_style",    'default')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot((0,1),(0.5,0.5), "--",lw=2);
ax1.plot((0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1),(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), "go--",markersize=20)
ax1.text(0.25, 0.5, "HardToRead", fontsize=12,ha="center",va="center", bbox=dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.1", fc='white', ec="white", lw=1,alpha=0.1))
ax1.text(0.75, 0.5, "EasyToRead", fontsize=12,ha="center",va="center", bbox=dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.1", fc='white', ec="white", lw=1,alpha=0.9))
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5,  "CrossTalk",  fontsize=12,ha="center",va="center", rotation=90, bbox=dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.1", fc='white', ec="white", lw=1,alpha=0.6))
```